# Триггеры SQL Server

Tags: sql

Напишите, пожалуйста, любой пример триггера, выдающего сообщение при ошибке. Хоть какой..

Answer (score 2):

```
 CREATE
TRIGGER HotelSuitesSchedule_upd
ON dbo.HotelSuitesSchedule
for UPDATE
AS
begin
--
SET NOCOUNT ON
--
declare @n as int

  if exists
  (select i.id
    from inserted i inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id
     where (i.seat1>0 and d.seat1>0 and i.seat1<>d.seat1) or
    (i.seat2>0 and d.seat2>0 and i.seat2<>d.seat2))
   begin
    select @n=hs.RoomNumber
     from inserted i inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id
        left join HotelSuites hs with(nolock) on i.ID_HotelSuite=hs.ID
     where (i.seat1>0 and d.seat1>0 and i.seat1<>d.seat1) or
    (i.seat2>0 and d.seat2>0 and i.seat2<>d.seat2)
    RAISERROR ('Место в номере № %d уже забронировано!', 16, 1,@n) with SETERROR
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Для MSSQL, вешаем на таблицу `dbo.MyTable` триггер на вставку:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTable_OnInsert ON  dbo.MyTable
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(255)
    SELECT @name=i.name FROM inserted i

    IF @name ='Foo'
      RAISERROR ('Внимание! Попытка записать Foo!', 16, 1)
END
```

Если теперь попытаться добавить строку, содержащую в качестве поля `name` строковое выражение `'Foo'`, получим сообщение об ошибке:

> --------------------------- Среда Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> Express
> --------------------------- Ни одной строки не было обновлено.
>
> Данные в строке 1 не были
> зафиксированы. Источник ошибки: .Net
> SqlClient Data Provider. Сообщение об
> ошибке: Внимание! Попытка записать
> Foo!
>
> Исправьте ошибку и повторите попытку
> или нажмите клавишу ESC, чтобы
> отменить изменения. 
> --------------------------- ОК   Справка

Comment: А точно сработает? Где-то читал, что триггер FOR выполняется в той же транзакции, что и DML по таблице, а триггер AFTER - в отдельной транзакции, т.е. RAISEERROR на транзакцию вставки не повлияет. Я не прав?

Comment: ну, я ж проверил перед тем как постить, раз даже сообщение об ошибке предоставил )

Comment: Хотя вы, похоже, правы. Попробовал вставку запросом, а не вводом непосредственно в таблицу через Management Studo. Не откатывает. Хотя у ТС пока такого требования и не было.

Comment: А попробуйте переделать триггер на FOR и проверить через запрос? Откатывает?

Comment: Не откатывает. Нужно явно делать rollback transaction.